# Python/Excel - Merge .xlsx workbooks from file into .csv

Tags: python, excel, csv, export-to-csv, xlrd

Attempting to compile multiple .xlsx workbooks from a file into a single .csv

Loop I've created is only capturing the first workbook from the file.

How can I alter this to capture all workbooks in a file? Data is only on Sheet1 from all workbooks

```
import os
import xlrd
import csv

rootdir = r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\Mults'
filenames = []
for subdir, dir, files in os.walk(rootdir):
   for file in files:
      filenames.append(os.path.join(subdir, file))
      wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(subdir, file))
      sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
      with open('acit_multsTEST.csv','wb') as f:
        c = csv.writer(f)
        for r in range(sh.nrows):
            c.writerow(sh.row_values(r))
```

I appreciate any help!

Thank you!

Comment: Are there subdirs containing workbooks under your root dir? If not then you don't need to use `walk` but can use `glob` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have to do the following.

- Get a list of all the workbooks
- Open a main csv to append all your data to
- Iterate through your list of workbooks
- Append each sheet to your csv

  ```
  import glob
  import os
  import xlrd
  import csv

  ROOTDIR = r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\Mults'
  wb_pattern = os.path.join(ROOTDIR, '*.xlsx')

  workbooks = glob.glob(wb_pattern)

  with open('out.csv', 'wb') as outcsv:
      writer = csv.writer(outcsv)
      for wb in workbooks:
          book_path = os.path.join(ROOTDIR, wb)
          book =  xlrd.open(book_path)
          sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
          for row_num in xrange(sheet.nrows):
             row = sheet(row_num) 
             writer.writerow(row)
  ```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! That worked. Now I just need to format the data. I appreciate it.

Comment: Looks like it was just the `os.path.walk` going wrong, then?

Comment: recursion is tricky at the best of times and in this instance wasn't needed. simplifying it using `glob` seemed wise. i thought that your suggestion to move it out of the loop should have worked but when op was still stuck i thought it best to start over.

Comment: @MikeV. formatting data in a csv should not really be necessary. I would in general rely on whatever was consuming the data to worry about formatting it. What is the csv for? A database load?

Comment: @b10n Yes, this is for a database load. What I meant by formatting was to format the data during extraction. Each spread sheet has a 2 row header that would be ideal to exclude during the compilation of workbooks. So that the data arrays into uniformed columns.

Comment: If that is your use case then i strongly advise you to check out the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library. It can parse spreadsheets easier then xlrd and excels in ETL type situations.